# Cache Control Headers with IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, cache, http-headers

I'm trying to wrap my head around client side (web browser) caching and how it works in relation to IIS 7.5 cache control headers.

In particular:

1. If we want to force clients to reload cached resources, how must IIS be configured?
2. Do we need to set expire web content immediately if the resources on the server have a more recent Modified Date (or ETag value)?
3. Right now we're not setting any cache headers. So if I set a cache header of no-cache (which I think is the equivalent of expire web content immediately) will that force the web browser to obtain a new version of a particular file.  Or will the browser only request a new version after it deems its current copy to be stale and then from that point forward not cache it?

Would a best practice be to set a cache control flag of 1 week, then 8 days before I know I am going to make a change set the cache control down to for instance 30 minutes?

But if I do that and then need to immediately expire an item from users caches because there was an issue with it how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

One way to understand client/user agent caching is to view the browser as implementing an intermediate cache for itself (which in fact it does, addressed by `Cache-Control: private`). This abstracts all the terminology to simple patterns of request and response, and in most cases the browser cache behaves the same as a proxy or intermediate cache. Keeping this in mind is helpful when reading the authoritative documentation on the subject in IETF RFC 2616: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.

1. Set the "Expires" header to "Immediately" (which sends `Cache-Control: no-cache`) as described at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(v=ws.10).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689443(v=vs.90).aspx.
2. No. If you don't send any Cache-Control headers, IIS should send the latest version of the resource and a client should recognize that from either the Last-Modified header or the ETag.
3. Your first statement is correct: sending `no-cache` will instruct the client to request the resource every time, even if it has already cached it. Some clients misbehave and cache such resources anyway, but you can also use `must-revalidate` to ensure that it gets a fresh copy

As for best practices, how long you cache depends on your application and users' needs. You can always send `Cache-Control: must-revalidate` to solve the issues mentioned, so there is no need to globally change your cache expiration.